# What does this mean: require_once(): Failed opening required '../../wp-includes/pluggable.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php71/lib/php')

Tags: wordpress

I'm very new to WP and I don't get what this means. What do I do to handle this?

I've tried the following code:

```
    require_once("../../wp-includes/pluggable.php");
```

What I'm trying to do is to make the "is_user_logged_in()" WP function available in my code.

Here is ta link to there the function is located at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/

Comment: You don't need to require/include anything to use that function.  You just call it.  Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to post your code for a proper answer. That message is a standard error caused by something elsewhere.

Have you by any chance edited core files?